# ActionFilterAttribute: HttpContext.Request.Body always empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httprequest, .net-7.0, actionfilterattribute

I am trying to get the request body in an `ActionFilterAttribute`.

The JSON value is always "". I am using .NET7.0 and I also added below code to `Program.cs`

```cs
.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        try
        {
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();
            await next();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
         .
         .
         .
```

The attribute code snippet:

```cs
 public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {

        var expectedModel = context.ActionArguments.Values.FirstOrDefault();
        if (expectedModel == null)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("Model empty.");
            return;
        }

        var requestBodyStream = new MemoryStream();
        await context.HttpContext.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(requestBodyStream);
        requestBodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var json = await new StreamReader(requestBodyStream).ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

[RequestBody](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGsrA.png)

My controller method:

```cs
    [HttpPost("scoring/add")]
    [JsonModelValidationAttribute]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddScoringResult([FromBody] ScoreModel model)
    {
      //I am going to add logic.
    }
```

I want to get the request body and compare the `ScoreModel` to check for any misspelled property. How to get the body from the request?

Classes and example:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class JsonModelValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {

        var expectedModel = context.ActionArguments.Values.FirstOrDefault();
        if (expectedModel == null)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("Model empty.");
            return;
        }

        var requestBodyStream = new MemoryStream();
        await context.HttpContext.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(requestBodyStream);
        requestBodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var json = await new StreamReader(requestBodyStream).ReadToEndAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

ScoreModel

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace Scoring.Data.Custom;

public class ScoreModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }


    public int Score { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```cs
using Scoring.Data.Custom;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Scoring.API.Custom;

[ApiController]
public class ScoringController : ControllerBase
{

    public ScoringController()
    {

    }

    [HttpPost("scoring/add")]
    [JsonModelValidationAttribute]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddScoringResult([FromBody] ScoreModel model)
    {

        return Ok(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a [mre] including the middleware registration.

Comment: @GuruStron I added the all classes related this issues.

Answer (score 1):

After enabling buffering (do not forget that it should be placed early in the pipeline) you need to not forget to rewind the **incoming** stream (depending where along the pipeline you are you might need to rewind it before and/or after reading it). In this particular case the following will fix the issue:

```cs
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    // ...
    context.HttpContext.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // <--- here
    
    var requestBodyStream = new MemoryStream();
    await context.HttpContext.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(requestBodyStream);
    requestBodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var json = await new StreamReader(requestBodyStream).ReadToEndAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

Also I would recommend to dispose the created stream and do not forget to call `await next()`:

```cs
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    var expectedModel = context.ActionArguments.Values.FirstOrDefault();
    if (expectedModel == null)
    {
        context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("Model empty.");
        return;
    }

    var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
    request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body, leaveOpen: true))
    {
        var json = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }

    request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    await next();
}
```